# How to make devstack persist changes after reboot of system in ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: openstack, devstack

I created a debian image which is of QCOW2 type and launched a instance using the same image.
instance was successfully running and image creation was succesful too.
I want to persist this and all other changes i will make into devstack even after host reboot.

I tried running:
    screen -c stack-screenrc

but running that script shows the following results....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tyVI.jpg)

I referred following link

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/5423/rebooting-with-devstack/

but rejoin-stack.sh script doesn't exists in my devstack.
any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to write the next:

- `script /dev/null`
- `screen -c stack-screenrc`